# if i make an update i get

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

```
sascha@sascha-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] Passwort für sascha: 
OK:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
OK:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                    
Holen:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
OK:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Holen:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Holen:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Holen:12 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [955 kB]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Holen:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [466 kB]
Holen:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [265 kB]
Holen:15 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [567 kB]
Holen:16 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [768 kB]
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Holen:17 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [303 kB]
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Holen:18 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.468 B]
Holen:19 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.768 B]
Holen:20 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24,4 kB]
Holen:21 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58,2 kB]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Fehl:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Es wurden 3.733 kB in 2 s geholt (1.530 kB/s).       
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
sascha@sascha-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC:
```

Comment: i get this error if i try to make an update ( sudo apt update ) I dont install enything. I need help. Thank you

Comment: Please replace the command output to english one `LC_ALL=C sudo apt update` .

Comment: I am not so good in reading this, but it looks like a dns error

Comment: Ehh, sudo apt update does NOT update your pc, it will search for updates. To update, use sudo apt upgrade

Comment: Please add output of `grep -r DEP-11 /etc/apt/` to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar location really returns 404 even without proxy.

On fresh 20.04 LTS I can't reproduce this problem.

You can try the following commands to fix the issue:

```
# remove local package lists
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -rf

# re-add PPA again
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
```

Comment: Thhhannk you it works i can make updates and upgrades

Comment: @SaschaSchmittinger if it fixed it for you, then please click the gray checkmark icon under the voting widget on this answer; that will make it green. There will be much rejoice.